# WordPress Custom query - show only one latest post a day by author

Tags: wordpress

I have a page to show all published posts and I want to add filter that filters out multiple posts in a same day by same author.

So if one author wrote 3 posts in a same day, only show the ONE latest post from that author. Apply same rule to all authors in the site.

How can I achieve this?

So I found this but still not sure how am I going to get all the dates that user wrote posts.

```
add_action( 'post_creation_limits_custom_checks', 'post_per_day_limit' );

function post_per_day_limit( $type, $user_id ) {
    global $bapl,$wpdb;

    // safe check: Plugin installed?
    ! isset( $bapl ) AND _doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__, sprintf( 'You need to %sinstall the needed Plugin%s', '<a href="http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bainternet-posts-creation-limits/">', '</a>' ), 0 );

    $time_in_days = 1; // 1 means in last day
    $count = $wpdb->get_var(
        $wpdb->prepare("
            SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM $wpdb->posts 
            WHERE post_status = 'publish' 
            AND post_type = %s 
            AND post_author = %s
            AND post_date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL %s DAY)",
            $type,
            $user_id,
            $time_in_days
        )
    );
    if ( 0 < $count ) 
        $count = number_format( $count );

    // here you can check since we have the $count ex: 
    // limit for 2 posts a day
    if ( 1 < $count ) {
        // return limit reached message using the plugin class
        exit( $bapl->bapl_not_allowed( 'you can not posts more them two posts a day' ) );
    }
    // else do nothing
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you've tried that isn't working and I'm sure someone will be happy to point you in the right direction.

Comment: I found this on WordPress codex. <?php
function count_user_posts_by_type( $userid, $post_type = 'post' ) {
 global $wpdb;

 $where = get_posts_by_author_sql( $post_type, true, $userid );

 $count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts $where" );

   return apply_filters( 'get_usernumposts', $count, $userid );
}
?> and thinking I can some how add date filter in there?? However, I'm still not sure of the whole concept of how to set this up.